# STM32 SPI DMA issue

Tags: stm32, spi, dma

I have two MCU, STM32H755ZIT6 as Master TRANSMIT ONLY and STM32F103C8T6 as Slave RECEIVE ONLY.
The Master MCU is sending 18 bytes all the time via DMA and the Slave device is receiving it also with DMA. Both Master and Slave SPI clock frequencies, polarities, data frame formats are the same.

Here is the Slave's source code

```
`SPI_InitDMA();

 while (1)
 {

   if(SPI_TxIsComplete() == 0x01U)
   {
      memcpy(buffer, dma, DMA_RX_SIZE);

      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, buffer, DMA_RX_SIZE, 1000);

      HAL_Delay(50); // I NEED THIS DELAY !

      SPI_Receive_DMA(dma, DMA_RX_SIZE);
   }
 }`
```

Here is SPI DMA initialization

```
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN;
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN;
RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA1EN;
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;

AFIO->MAPR &= ~(AFIO_MAPR_SPI1_REMAP);

// Software CS Pin
GPIOA->CRL |= (GPIO_CRL_CNF4_0);
GPIOA->CRL &= ~(GPIO_CRL_CNF4_1);
GPIOA->CRL |= (GPIO_CRL_MODE4_0 | GPIO_CRL_MODE4_1);

// SCK Pin
GPIOA->CRL |= (GPIO_CRL_CNF5_0);
GPIOA->CRL &= (GPIO_CRL_CNF5_1);
GPIOA->CRL |= (GPIO_CRL_MODE5_0 | GPIO_CRL_MODE5_1);

// MOSI Pin
GPIOA->CRL &= ~(GPIO_CRL_CNF7_0);
GPIOA->CRL |= (GPIO_CRL_CNF7_1);
GPIOA->CRL &= ~(GPIO_CRL_MODE7_0 | GPIO_CRL_MODE7_1);

//
// Setup SPI1
//

SPI1->CR1 &= ~DV_SPI_CR1_SPE;

SPI1->CR1 &= ~(DV_SPI_CR1_BIDIMODE | DV_SPI_CR1_BIDIOE | DV_SPI_CR1_CRCEN |
              DV_SPI_CR1_CRCNEXT | DV_SPI_CR1_DFF | DV_SPI_CR1_SSI |
              DV_SPI_CR1_LSBFIRST);
SPI1->CR1 &= ~(DV_SPI_CR1_BR_2 | DV_SPI_CR1_BR_1 | DV_SPI_CR1_BR_0);
SPI1->CR1 &= ~(DV_SPI_CR1_MSTR);
SPI1->CR1 &= ~(DV_SPI_CR1_CPOL | DV_SPI_CR1_CPHA);
SPI1->CR1 |= DV_SPI_CR1_RXONLY;

SPI1->CR1 |= DV_SPI_CR1_SSM;

//
// Clear control register
//

SPI1->CR2 &= ~(0x00FF);

//
// Setup DMA1 Channel 2
//

DMA1_Channel2->CCR &= ~(DV_DMA_CCRX_MEM2MEM | DV_DMA_CCRX_PL_1 | DV_DMA_CCRX_PL_0);
DMA1_Channel2->CCR &= ~(DV_DMA_CCRX_MSIZE_1 | DV_DMA_CCRX_MSIZE_0);
DMA1_Channel2->CCR &= ~(DV_DMA_CCRX_PSIZE_1 | DV_DMA_CCRX_PSIZE_0);
DMA1_Channel2->CCR &= ~(DV_DMA_CCRX_PINC);
DMA1_Channel2->CCR &= ~(DV_DMA_CCRX_CIRC);
DMA1_Channel2->CCR &= ~(DV_DMA_CCRX_DIR);
DMA1_Channel2->CCR &= ~(DV_DMA_CCRX_HTIE);

DMA1_Channel2->CCR |= (DV_DMA_CCRX_MINC);

//
// Clear DMA channel 2 interrupt flags
//

DMA1_Channel2->CCR &= ~DV_DMA_CCRX_EN;

DMA1->IFCR |= DV_DMA_IFCR_CTCIF2;
DMA1->IFCR |= DV_DMA_IFCR_CTEIF2;

//
// Enable DMA channel 2 interrupts
//

DMA1_Channel2->CCR &= ~(DV_DMA_CCRX_HTIE);
DMA1_Channel2->CCR |= (DV_DMA_CCRX_TEIE);
DMA1_Channel2->CCR |= (DV_DMA_CCRX_TCIE);

//
// Enable SPI
//

SPI1->CR2 |= DV_SPI_CR2_RXDMAEN;
//SPI1->CR2 |= DV_SPI_CR2_RXNEIE;
//SPI1->CR2 |= DV_SPI_CR2_ERRIE;
SPI1->CR1 |= DV_SPI_CR1_SPE;

//
// Set interrupt
//

//NVIC_SetPriority(SPI1_IRQn, NVIC_EncodePriority(NVIC_GetPriorityGrouping(), 1, 0));
//NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI1_IRQn);

NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn, NVIC_EncodePriority(NVIC_GetPriorityGrouping(), 1, 0));
NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn);
```

And Slave Receive code

```
u8 SPI_Receive_DMA(u8* buffer, u16 size)
{
  u8 err = ERROR_NO;

  tx_done_ = 0x00U;

  DMA1_Channel2->CCR &= ~DV_DMA_CCRX_EN;

  DMA1_Channel2->CNDTR = size;
  DMA1_Channel2->CMAR = (u32)buffer;
  DMA1_Channel2->CPAR = (u32)&SPI1->DR;

  DMA1_Channel2->CCR |= DV_DMA_CCRX_EN;

  return err;
}
```

And Slave's DMA handler

```
void SPI_HandlDMAInterrupt(void)
{
  volatile u32 reg_isr = DMA1->ISR;

  //
  // Check transfer complete flag
  //

  if((reg_isr & DV_DMA_IFCR_CTCIF2) != 0x00U)
  {
    DMA1->IFCR |= DV_DMA_IFCR_CGIF2;

    tx_done_ = 0x01U;
  }

  //
  // Check transfer error flag
  //

  if((reg_isr & DV_DMA_IFCR_CTEIF2) != 0x00U)
  {
    asm("nop");
  }
}
```

So , problem is that I'm always getting Overrun flag and data inside the DMA buffer is sometimes SHIFTED or it's wrong data.
I know that Master is sending the data all the time, but that's why I do have  DMA_IFCR_CTCIF2 on Slave side which indicates that the DMA transfer is
complete and I can call SPI_Receive_DMA again and there should not be any OVR flag.
Also I checked SPI communication via Logic analyzer and everything is ok.
BTW do I need CS Pin at all in this case (Master Transmit only, Slave Receive only) ?
I do have the same OVR flag and shifted data even with Hardware NSS mode.

Comment: You need the CS at least once, to synchronize the bits into bytes. Otherwise one device is just transmitting a constant stream of bits and the receiver has no idea which bits belong to which bytes, or which bit or byte is the first or last in the transmission. Which also means if the transmitter and receiver boards boot at different times, they cannot know when to start transmitting or receiving in order to transmit and receive so that bits and bytes are synchronized.

Comment: @Justme Yes I'm setting CS Pin low before transfer on Master side and after transmit I set CS Pin high, also I connected Master's CS pin to the Slave's CS pin (both with software NSS). Should I set CS pin low and high in Slave too? Slave's CS pin must be in input mode right?

Comment: Do you think software NSS applies for a slave, if you need the slave board to sync itself to the NSS signal wire sent from the master?

Comment: @Justme so it's useless to use software NSS? I have to use HARDWARE NSS?

Comment: In software NSS, the SPI receiver ignores the hardware NSS pin and you are in software control when you want to enable and disable the reception. If you don't control it in software, then you are not synchronized. At least you should read the hardware IO pin in software and then when you see it go enabled or disabled you can then set software NSS active to be synchronized.

Comment: @Justme To be clear, on Slave side , BEFORE receiving any data, I should read hardware IO pin (coming from Master) and if it's high then I can start receiving, high because if CS is low it  means that data transmission is in progress and we may receive wrong/shifted data. I'm I correct? and also on the slave side I can not set IO pin right?just via register.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151683/discussion-between-alatriste-and-justme).